# Dump RDS PostgreSQL instance databases, users & roles with passwords

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-web-services, psql, rds

I am attempting to restore an RDS snapshot to a reserved instance. The instance size we reserved (m5.large) is available when creating a new instance, but not available when restoring a snapshot.

Can pg_dumpall be used in RDS or is there a way to create a superuser within the instance?

If neither of the above, what process is necessary to export all Users & Roles with passwords, globals, and databases. Essentially simulate the snapshot-restore process. Thank you!